# Does BNFC support the symbol '|'?

Tags: bnfc

There is a simple example in BNFC's documentation.

```
Char_a. Char ::= "a" ;
Char_b. Char ::= "b" ;
```

I try to rewrite it by using union `|`

```
Char_a.  Char ::= "a" | "b" ;
```

but then in this case I got an error `bnfc: user error (syntax error at line 1 before | b ;)`

It seems that BNFC really not likes `|`. However, I find `|` can be used in rules statement.

`rules Boolen ::= "True" | "False";`
this can be compiled successfully. So I would like to know the reason for the error in my rewriting and where the union symbol can be used.